# Installing packages on Macbook Pro (MacTex BasicTex)

Tags: packages, installing, mactex

I have been looking around a lot and haven't found anything which helps my scenario or thoroughly explains.

I'm trying to use LaTeX on my new, shiny Macbook Pro. I installed TeXStudio and the BasicTeX (https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) smaller installation of MacTeX (because I want to keep as much of my hard drive free as possible for other things) How do I go about installing packages such as chemfig or feynmf or amsmath? (P.S. are amsmath and tikz pre installed?)

Comment: Use TeX Live Utility.

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid you are in for a frustrating time. Are you really so short of disk space that installing MacTeX is out of the question? Especially if you anyway need things like TikZ etc. You will spend a great deal of time this way installing things, figuring out what to install, wondering why it isn't working etc.

Comment: I doubt PGF/TikZ comes with the basic BasicTeX: that would mean about 10% of BasicTeX is saved for PGF/TikZ...

Answer (score 4):

The answer is [Will Robertson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/179/will-robertson)'s comment:

> Use TeX Live Utility.

You should be able to access it from Spotlight or Launchpad.

I recently installed BasicTeX myself, and I'm fairly sure `amsmath` and `mathtools` were already included. I don't ever remember installing them myself, but my TeX Live Utility is listing them as "installed." `tikz` is not pre-installed.